# Invalid template file on custom module

Tags: magento2

**Issue**

`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'TT::calculator.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'calculator.tab'`

**Layout Location:**

*app/code/TT/Calculator/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="calculator.tab" template="TT::calculator.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Calculator</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Template Location:**

*app/code/TT/Calculator/view/frontend/templates/calculator.phtml*

**Questions**

1. I've seen some solutions where the *.phtml file is saved in *app/design* but I'm trying to get this to work in *app/code*. What have I missed?
2. Also, does this "extend" catalog_product_view.xml or replace it?

Comment: You have to change to TT_Calculator::calculator.phtml.

Comment: I typo'd after fixing, making me think it didn't work. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.You have to change the code to `TT_Calculator::calculator.phtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="calculator.tab" template="TT_Calculator::calculator.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Calculator</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

2.Magento will check all the layout (XML file) in all the modules and merge them, not extend.

Answer (score 5):

Your template file location should be **TT_Calculator::calculator.phtml**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="calculator.tab" template="TT_Calculator::calculator.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Calculator</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue now. The problem was the allow symlink of the system config:

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/template/allow_symlink 1 --lock-env
```